# How to dynamically throw Exception based on Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am implementing an Error Handling module in my `asp.net 4.5` web App.

I have created an error throwing  GUI which dynamically populates a dropdown selector from a `list<Types>` of `Exception` types for a specific  (`Exception`) assembly.

I then want to throw the error selected to test how it will be captured/handled.

I have this partially working as I am able to throw an exception based on the type, but I have to cast it as a base exception type. The actual exception gets ‘preserved’ as an `innerException`, but I want to try and throw the specific exception.

So my question is: how can I throw an exception dynamically given just the exception Type?

```
 protected void ddlExcep_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Type> ExTypes = GetExceptionList();  //list of SystemException.Exception (from assembly  System.SystemException)
        DropDownList Exceptions = (DropDownList)sender;
        string exc =  Exceptions.SelectedValue.Replace("System.","");
        Type ExcType = (from E in  ExTypes where E.Name == exc select  E).FirstOrDefault();
        throw (SystemException)Activator.CreateInstance(ExcType);    
    }
```

It is not necessary to show how I derived the list but just for clarity
Here is the code that shows how the List:

```
public static T Instantiate<T>() where T : class
{
        return  System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T)) as T;
}

public static List<Type> FindAllDerivedTypes<T>()
{
    return FindAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)));
}

private  List<Type> GetExceptionList()
{
    List<Type> listExTypes = FindAllDerivedTypes<SystemException>();
    return listExTypes;      
}
```

Comment: Hang on, the innerException should always be null with the code you're showing. It looks like you're already throwing an object of the type you'd like. Could you explain further?

Comment: I was just about to type same..And more over why we cast it as SystemException.. ? And wouldn't it better to check the types instead of string comparison ?

Comment: This code really makes no sense, you need to give us more information and the actual code you are using.

Comment: @DavidG exTpes is a list<Types> derived from the base System.SystemException

Comment: @Cameron this code will continue onto the next line where it will generate an unhandled exception. the exception type I am throwing will be captured as its inner exception

Comment: And what is the outer exception?

Comment: @DavidG  and all  the main(outer)  exception is:  System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
the Inner Exception is: the derived Type that was selected.

Comment: Ah, I see. The exception is being thrown properly, it just wasn't being caught by your code. So the framework caught it somewhere and wrapped it in another exception.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the comments made me look back and realize that the casting to `SystemException` was not the problem but rather that I intentionally eliminated `Page_Error` method from my page thus causing the code to continue running to the next line which generated a  `System.Web.HttpUnhandledException` once I added my

```
 private void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //handle code
 }
```

The correct exception was thrown/captured